# Issue with i18n parsing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, i18next

I am getting JSON fro backend, which I need to parse on UI.
For all the keys from the JSON, I have to translate them and show on UI.

Eg: 
i18n.t('key') will give me translated value.

But for some keys like 'name', 'date'
Eg:
i18n.t('name')
translation is giving following output 
"key 'translation:name (en-US)' returned a object instead of string."

Could you please help me how to deal with this scenerio.

Comment: Please share a code sample.

Comment: Handlebar helper:
        Handlebars.registerHelper('t', function() {
         var params = getParamsFromArgs(arguments).join('');
         var result = params && i18n.t(params) || '';
            return new Handlebars.SafeString(result);
        });

template in html:

<div> {{t 'name'}} </div>

or in Jquery

$.t('name')

its giving me error instead of replace values from messages.property

Comment: try i18n.t('key', { returnObjects: true }); and you will see name returns an object and not a string (per default without returnObjects option i18next allows only string values as valid translations)

Answer (score -1):

If you have for example following JSON from your service

```
    {
       "i18n": {
          "name": "translation1",
          "name2": "translation2"
        }
    }
```

You can just use it as following

```
    var mytranslation = getTranslationsFromService();

    console.log(mytranslation.i18n.name)    //result: translation1
    console.log(mytranslation.i18n.name2)    //result: translation2

    var getTranslationsFromService = function() {
       //Get result from service, where the result looks like the JSON above.
    }
```

I hope I could help.

Kind regards.